# How to while loop distinct data?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, unique, distinct

Let's Say I have Data...
ID... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
FirstName... Donald, Tabatha, Jeremy, Samuel, Donald, Tabatha
LastName... Faulknor, Kolasa, Jones, Jackson, Faulknor, Kolasa

In this example, I would want to display
Donald Faulknor, Tabatha Kolasa, Jeremy Jones, Samuel Jackson

I can either display all data (repeating the duplicate entries) or, if I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

then I will only display the first instance, which in this case would be Donald Faulknor.  Here's my code...

```
$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE lowerID = :lowerIDb || higherID = :higherIDb";
    $stmt55 = $pdo->prepare($sql55);
    $stmt55->bindValue(':lowerIDb',$user_id);
    $stmt55->bindValue(':higherIDb',$user_id);
    $stmt55->execute();
    while($row55 = $stmt55->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $lowerID55 = $row55['lowerID'];
        $higherID55 = $row55['higherID'];
        if($lowerID55 == $user_id) { $user_id55 = $higherID55; } elseif($higherID55 == $user_id) { $user_id55 = $lowerID55; }
        $sql56 = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id55";
        $stmt56 = $pdo->prepare($sql56);
        $stmt56->bindValue(':user_id55',$user_id55);
        $stmt56->execute();
        while($row56 = $stmt56->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id56 = $row56['user_id'];
            $sql58 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id58";
            $stmt58 = $pdo->prepare($sql58);
            $stmt58->bindValue(':user_id58',$id56);
            $stmt58->execute();
            while($row58 = $stmt58->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $firstname56 = $row58['firstname'];
            $lastname56 = $row58['lastname'];
            $profilePhoto56 = $row58['profilePhoto'];
            $sql57 = "SELECT * from photos WHERE id = :profilePhotoa";
            $stmt57 = $pdo->prepare($sql57);
            $stmt57->bindValue(':profilePhotoa',$profilePhoto56);
            $stmt57->execute();
            while($row57 = $stmt57->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $profilePhotoPath57 = $row57['path'];
            echo '';
            echo ' '.$firstname56.' '.$lastname56.'';
        }
    }
    }}
```

To better understand the above code... I have messages to and from users, of course, there will be many to and from the same users.  I'm trying to get their name (the recipient) to show once in a side bar (indicating messages from/to that person.  Let's say for example, I have 20 messages to and from one person.  I can either get the name to repeat twenty times (not using DISTINCT) or I can only get one person's name to show (using DISTINCT).  So if there's 8 people to send this user an email, only one name will show.

Much help is greatly appreciated.  For questions or more elaboration, please feel free to ask questions.  Thank You! :)

Comment: You would join email table and users table together, and then sort by recipient_id. Run foreach() loop on results, and keep track on recipient ID change. When ID changes, you print new name. This will result Recipient name printed once in 1st column, and senders printed on the 2nd column.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I was afraid of that kind of response.  The reason for my nested while loops is because I struggle with joining tables.  But I'll see what I can try to figure out.  I really need to just understand the concept of joining tables.